# Trigger FileSystemWatcher events manually

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, filesystemwatcher

I'm developping a file system driver.
A bit like a shared folder or a network drive.

Thus, from a specific computer perspective, some file changes may not originate from writes on this computer.

<strike>For what I understand of its implentation, FSW is intercepting Win api calls to trigger those changes. But they are none here.</strike> 
(not the case, as mentioned in comments)

Thus if someone is watching file system events (i.e. has a `FileSystemWatcher` listening for changes), he/she will not receive any notification.

**So the question is:** How to manually trigger those events ? Is there a solution i'm missing ?

Preferably in C#, but a C++ solution would suit me.

ps: To achieve this, i'm currently triggering some "fake" writes to my driver that my driver ignores (i'm self calling me via the win API), but this method is definitively not clean, and i experienced some drawbacks (amongst them: a kernel deadlock...).

Comment: *"FSW is intercepting Win api"* - I believe this assumption is invalid.

Comment: @IInspectable is correct. It isn't "intercepting" Windows API calls. It is just a wrapper around the [`ReadDirectoryChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx) API function. I believe (although you should verify this by reading the documentation) that a driver will be sent the `IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL` request when an application calls `ReadDirectoryChanges`, so you should just be responding to this.

Comment: @IInspectable okay thanks, i misunderstood that. But my question is still valid, i assume

Comment: you in general need call [`FsRtlNotifyFullChangeDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547026(v=vs.85).aspx) in own driver. when process <`IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL`, `IRP_MN_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIRECTORY` >

Comment: A file system that has received an IRP with major function code `IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL`, minor function code `IRP_MN_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIRECTORY`, calls `FsRtlNotifyFilterChangeDirectory` to create a notify structure to hold the `IRP` and add the notify structure to the notify list for the current volume.

When a change occurs to the directory, the file system calls [`FsRtlNotifyFilterReportChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547018(v=vs.85).aspx) to complete the pending `IRP_MN_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIRECTORY` requests in the notify list.

Comment: @RbMm  i'm reading about that. Thanks. I just had a misconception on how things are wired up for this (i thought FSW was some sort of minifilter, i dont know how i missed it)